# sb-ext:defglobal access disassembly different between REPL and .lisp file

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I'm trying to make a global variable by using `sb-ext:defglobal` (actually by using quicklisp library [global-vars](https://github.com/lmj/global-vars) which wraps it and several other implementation-specific mechanics, but it does not matter). I'm having the following code in test.lisp file:

```
(sb-ext:defglobal *test* 42)
(defun test ()  *test*)
```

Then I call `(compile-file "test.lisp")` and `(load "test")`. After that, the `test` function disassembly looks like the following:

```
 (disassemble #'test)

; disassembly for TEST
; Size: 27 bytes. Origin: #x52C519CC                          ; TEST
; CC:       498B4510         MOV RAX, [R13+16]                ; thread.binding-stack-pointer
; D0:       488945F8         MOV [RBP-8], RAX
; D4:       488B05C5FFFFFF   MOV RAX, [RIP-59]                ; '*TEST*
; DB:       488B5001         MOV RDX, [RAX+1]
; DF:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; E2:       F8               CLC
; E3:       5D               POP RBP
; E4:       C3               RET
; E5:       CC10             INT3 16                          ; Invalid argument count trap
```

But when I define the very same function in REPL and try to disassemble it, it looks like this:

```
(defun test2 () *test*)
(disassemble #'test2)

; disassembly for TEST2
; Size: 24 bytes. Origin: #x52C51A5C                          ; TEST2
; 5C:       498B4510         MOV RAX, [R13+16]                ; thread.binding-stack-pointer
; 60:       488945F8         MOV [RBP-8], RAX
; 64:       488B142590EA3F50 MOV RDX, [#x503FEA90]            ; *TEST*
; 6C:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; 6F:       F8               CLC
; 70:       5D               POP RBP
; 71:       C3               RET
; 72:       CC10             INT3 16                          ; Invalid argument count trap
```

It is clear that when compiled from REPL, the code accessing the global variable is a bit more effective: it compiles to just one indirect `MOV` from some static address, while being compiled from the file, the access boils down to two indirect `MOV`s.
Supposedly I'm going to be using those global variables in some tight loops, so I'm concerned even about small scraps of effectiveness. So my question is, why the disassembly for the same function differs between REPL and .lisp file? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this with SBCL 2.0.0 on windows. I get identical 34 byte disassemblies with both methods. Maybe you have optimize declarations somewhere affecting the results?

Comment: @RowPJ Yeah, if you `slime-eval-region` the whole file, the results are indeed identical, but if you're loading fasl of that file (which will happen in real life, e.g. loading the asdf system containing that code), the difference in disassembly appears again. I've updated the question with that detail.

Comment: I tried again manually compiling and loading a file in the REPL, but I still get the same 34 byte disassembly.

Comment: @RowPJ That's weird, probably has something to do with Windows. Could you please post this disassembly?

Comment: I can't fit it in a comment, but I can show the different parts. It's identical to your 27 byte disassembly except this line was inserted after the second MOV instruction: "BB:       840425F8FF1020   TEST AL, [#x2010FFF8]            ; safepoint" and the third MOV instruction has "[RIP-73]" instead of "[RIP-59]"

Comment: I'm guessing the reason for the difference in your examples is that #'test doesn't know the address in memory of \*test\*'s data at compile time because the memory isn't allocated until load time, but #'test2 does since the memory has been allocated from the REPL by the time it's compiled. That's just speculation though. Maybe using block compilation in SBCL 2.0.2 could help.

Comment: Nope, block compilation didn't help :(

Comment: Also yes, under Windows SBCL 2.0.0 produces 2-instruction variable access, but under MacOS SBCL 2.0.5 produces 1-instruction sequence when the function is both `load`ed and defined in REPL. I'm assuming this is some sort of platform-specific optimization.